# escape or unescape not working for particular unicode String - Node Js

Tags: node.js

My Code is

```
  var a='{"D\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000":"\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00008\u0000-\u00000\u00009\u0000-\u00000\u00001\u0000","\u0000P\u0000a\u0000c\u0000k\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000":"\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m\u0000.\u0000a\u0000p\u0000p\u0000a\u0000p\u0000p\u0000o\u0000","\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00005\u00002\u0000","\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000U\u0000n\u0000i\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00001\u00004\u0000","\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000U\u0000p\u0000g\u0000r\u0000a\u0000d\u0000e\u0000s\u0000":"\u00002\u0000","\u0000T\u0000o\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000 \u0000U\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00000\u0000","\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000U\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00005\u00004\u0000","\u0000D\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000U\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000 \u0000U\u0000n\u0000i\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00001\u00004\u0000","\u0000A\u0000c\u0000t\u0000i\u0000v\u0000e\u0000 \u0000D\u0000e\u0000v\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000s\u0000":"\u00001\u00003\u00007\u0000","\u0000I\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000 \u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000t\u0000s\u0000":"\u00005\u00007\u0000","\u0000U\u0000p\u0000d\u0000a\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000t\u0000s\u0000":"\u00000\u0000","\u0000U\u0000n\u0000i\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000l\u0000l\u0000 \u0000e\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000t\u0000s\u0000":"\u00001\u00005\u0000"}'
console.log(escape(a));
a=escape(a);
console.log(unescape(a));
```

both returns only unicode string in node js server. but when it comes to browser it decodes normally.
Specific string is obtained from unicode CSV file via csvtojson npm Module.

Comment: what is the expected output you want to print?

Comment: stringifyed json string

Comment: escape and then unescape will just nullify each other.. its just as doing console.log(a) . Could you explain why you are escaping and unescaping it ?

Comment: actual thing is im getting a csv from a google cloud bucket. when converting specific csv file to json , it returns encoded json as given above. when i copy and paste it in console , it decodes automatically. but when printing in node js terminal it returns as unicode string as given.

Comment: I cannot able to add attachment , else Ill attach that CSV